# What version of DirectX does WPF's Viewport3D use?

Tags: wpf, 3d, directx, viewport3d

I am working on a project and need to display a 3D scene (with animation) within my WPF application. It should be a relatively simple scene, but the hardware it will run on might be pretty constrained, so I am concerned about performance and efficiency.

I am evaluating whether to use WPF's Viewport3D, but am concerned that it might be using DirectX 9 on the backend. Ideally I wouldn't mind DirectX 11 or 12, though I suppose 10 would be acceptable. I hear DirectX 9 is less performant, though, so I'd like to avoid that.

Does anyone know what version of DirectX WPF's Viewport3D leverages under the hood?

Thanks.

Comment: WPF is indeed using DirectX9: https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/c3b1ecefd9debf850b4757bb8d657b15af79469d/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/WpfGfx/core/common/d3dloader.cpp the problem is often not performance, but interoperability with more modern Windows techs (DirectX11, Visual Composition, Direct2D, XAML, WinUI, etc.), and also "airspace" issue, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For .NET Core there is an [open issue](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/2063) around improving the 3D features of WPF, including upgrading to a newer version of DirectX, which also confirms the current implementation.

> WPF still uses DX9 in both .NET Framework and .NET core.

Other references on that topic:

- [Source of `D3DLoader.h`](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/master/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/WpfGfx/core/common/D3DLoader.h) ([this](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/b697746306a695af80a756586cad3f84a62e366c/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/WpfGfx/core/common/D3DLoader.h#L80) line)
- [DirectX vs. WPF](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/72320ba5-0b0d-400f-a076-717520308638/directx-vs-wpf?forum=gametechnologiesdirectx101)
- [Add DirectX 11 or higher support for Net Core WPF](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/962231/add-directx-11-or-higher-support-for-net-core-wpf.html)
- [Graphics Rendering Tiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/graphics-rendering-tiers?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)